# Is there a way to present an iso file as a mock usb device?

Tags: iso-image

I am trying to mount an .iso image into virt-viewer so I can boot a VM off of it to recover a lost root password. However, it appears that virt-viewer can only share USB devices, and not ISO files. I know it is possible to mount an iso file as a loopback device, but is it possible to feign a USB device (make the system present the iso file as a usb disk).

Normally I would try recovering using GRUB, but it appears not to be working (the init=/bin/sh kills console access when I try to run it, using break.rd enforcing=0 is ignored and goes directly to the login prompt). The remaining option is booting off of an iso.

I have access to linux, osx, and windows machines so a solution for any of them would work.

Comment: Does it have to be USB, or will any removable disk do the job?

Comment: Specifically USB.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [virt-rescue](http://libguestfs.org/virt-rescue.1.html)?  I haven't tried it myself, but it seems to indicate that you can get a recovery shell.  I would think that you can reset the password for the root account that way.